# posting twice to the same page

Tags: php, html

I have a form to submit details to database, after processing the POST on the action page i have another form to upload a photo very closely related to the info provided on the previous form, in fact the image path is stored on the same record in the database, instead of having two pages / two steps process, is it possible to have them both on the same form?
i know that nesting forms is not possible, at the same time uploading the file requires a form. 
Using anchors and GET method is not acceptable in my application for the info is too sensitive to be revealed in URL

is there a way to workaround this?
thanks in advance

Comment: How about using sessions? Set the session on page 1, then read and reset on page 2.

Comment: You really those 2 steps or couldn't you display both in the form ?

Comment: What could stop you from having both in the same form ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

- either session variables (to temporarily store the first step of the form)
- or javascript to cycle through steps without refreshing the page

Comment: I think javascript (ajax) posts would be best, if I got the OP right.

Comment: Yeah that would be a bonus if he can use javascript

Answer (score 0):

How about using 2 fieldsets?

```
<form action="?">
    <fieldset>

       //input fields
       <input type="button" value="Next" id="btnNext">

    </fieldset>

    <fieldset>

       //foto input field
       <input type="button" value="Submit">

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Then in JS (with jQuery):

```
$("fieldset").eq(1).hide();

$("#btnNext").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $("fieldset").eq(0).hide();
   $("fieldset").eq(1).show();
});
```